# PHP image upload in admin section only allowing client to upload 19 images

Tags: php, file-upload, for-loop, image-upload, file-io

I've been working on a client's admin panel (A photography company uploading images to a client's gallery), when I took on the role as web developer, it only allowed him to upload **30 images**, even though there was **100 file upload boxes**. This was fixed simply by changing the **for loop to run 100 times**. This fixed this problem.

But recently, without even touching the code, my client can only upload **19 images**.. I haven't changed this form, he has previously uploaded 40+ images, so I don't quite understand what could have happened.. I've checked the code over and over, and can't quite seem to pinpoint the issue. Could this be server side, as I've recently moved from his **old developer's host** to **my hostgator account**. Maybe something in the htaccess? I add this because the **image label's update**, but not the **image itself** (*I can't find it uploaded either, after it has been posted, but my browser shows it uploading*)

Here is the edit gallery code itself, if it gives any assistance to the problem:

```
<?php
require_once("../conn.php");
require_once("access.php");
require_once("GalleryNavigation.php");
require_once("dThumbMaker.inc.php");

/////////////common varilable
$__table = "devbg_gallery";
$__page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$__page2 = "AddGallery.php";
$__id = "ItemID";
$__pagetitle = "GALLERY";
$__uploadfolder = "../myimages/";
$__thumbuploadfolder = "../myimages/thumbs/";
$__imageprefix = "Gallery";
$Thumb_Imgwidth = 200;
$Thumb_Imgheight = 77;
/////////////
if(isset($_POST[ds]))
{
    if(count($_POST['DelItem']) > '0')
    {
        while(list(, $value) = each($_POST['DelItem']))
        {
            $DelInfo = $value;
            $r2 = mysql_query("select * from ".$__table." where ".$__id." = '$DelInfo' ") or die(mysql_error());
            $a2 = mysql_fetch_array($r2);

            for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
            {
                if(file_exists($__uploadfolder.$a2['ItemImage'.$i]))
                {
                    unlink($__uploadfolder.$a2['ItemImage'.$i]);
                    unlink($__thumbuploadfolder.$a2['ItemImage'.$i]);
                }   
            }

            //delete the product
            mysql_query("delete from ".$__table." where ".$__id." = '".$DelInfo."' ") or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_POST[s100]))
{
    $MyProductName = mysql_escape_string(trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST[ProductName]))));
    $Description = mysql_escape_string(trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['Description']))));
    $Link = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['Link'])));
    $TopLabel = cleaninput($_POST['TopLabel'],"mres|he|tr");
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $NewTopLabelName = $TopLabel;

    if(!empty($_FILES['TopImage']['name']))
    {
        $NewTopImageName = $__imageprefix.$t.$_FILES['TopImage']['name'];
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['TopImage']['tmp_name'])) 
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['TopImage']['tmp_name'], $__uploadfolder.$NewTopImageName);
            $NewTopImageName = $NewTopImageName;
            $NewTopLabelName = $TopLabel;
            //lets make the thumb
            $tm = new dThumbMaker;
            $load = $tm->loadFile($__uploadfolder.$NewTopImageName);
            if($load === true)
            { // Note three '='
                $tm->cropCenter($Thumb_Imgwidth, $Thumb_Imgheight);
                $tm->build($__thumbuploadfolder.$NewTopImageName);
            }
            else
            {
                // Error returned.
                $error .= "Could not open the file '".$NewTopImageName."'.\n";
                $error .= "The error returned was: ";
                $error .= $load;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $NewTopImageName = $_POST['OldTopImage'];
        $NewTopLabelName = $NewTopLabelName;
    }

    for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++) //This is where I believe the problem is --------------------------------------------------------------------
    {   
        ${'NewsItemLabel'.$i} = cleaninput($_POST['ItemLabel'.$i],"mres|he|tr");
        $ItemLabels .= "ItemLabel".$i ." = '". cleaninput($_POST['ItemLabel'.$i],"mres|he|tr") ."',";
        if(!empty($_FILES['ItemImage'.$i]['name']))
        {
            ${'NewImageName'.$i} = $__imageprefix.$t.$_FILES['ItemImage'.$i]['name'];
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ItemImage'.$i]['tmp_name'])) 
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ItemImage'.$i]['tmp_name'], $__uploadfolder.${'NewImageName'.$i});
                //lets make the thumb
                $tm = new dThumbMaker;
                $load = $tm->loadFile($__uploadfolder.${'NewImageName'.$i});
                if($load === true)
                { // Note three '='
                    $tm->cropCenter($Thumb_Imgwidth, $Thumb_Imgheight);
                    $tm->build($__thumbuploadfolder.${'NewImageName'.$i});
                    $ItemImages .= "ItemImage".$i ." = '". ${'NewImageName'.$i} ."',";
                }
                else
                {
                    // Error returned.
                    $error .= "Could not open the file '".${'NewImageName'.$i}."'.\n";
                    $error .= "The error returned was: ";
                    $error .= $load;
                }
            } else {  }
        }
        else
        {
            ${'NewImageName'.$i} = $_POST['OldItemImage'.$i];
        }
    }

    if(empty($error))
    {
        //update the database
        $q1 = "update ".$__table." set 
                        ItemName = '".$MyProductName."',
                        Description = '".$Description."',
                        Link = '".$Link."',
                        TopImage = '$NewTopImageName',
                        Toplabel = '$NewTopLabelName',
                        ".$ItemImages.$ItemLabels."
                        status = '".$status."'

                        where ".$__id." = '".$_POST[$__id]."' ";

        mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<br><br><center>Gallery Updated</center>";
    }
}
if(!empty($_GET[$__id]))
{
   $_POST[$__id] = $_GET[$__id];
}
if(!empty($_POST[$__id]))
{
    //get the product info
    $r1 = mysql_query("select * from devbg_gallery where ".$__id." = '".$_POST[$__id]."' ") or die(mysql_error());
    $a1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1);

    echo $error;
?>
<form method=post action=EditGallery.php enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table align=center width=740>
<caption align=center><b>Gallery Name:</b></caption>
<tr>
    <td align='right'>Event Name:</td>
    <td><input type=text class=input name="ProductName" value="<?php echo $a1['ItemName'];?>"></td>
</tr>
<TR>
    <td align='right'>Description:</td>
    <td><textarea name="Description"cols=60 rows=10><?php echo $a1['Description'];?></textarea></td>
</TR>
<?php
if(!empty($a1['TopImage']))
{
    $v = $a1['TopImage'];
     echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td></td><td><img src='".$__uploadfolder.$v."' width='72' border='0'><br><a href='DeleteImage.php?".$__id."=".$a1[$__id]."&Type=gallery&file=".$v."&img=top'>Delete Image</a></td>";
     echo "</tr>";
}
?>
<tr>
    <td align='right'>Top Image:</td>
    <td><input type=file name=TopImage></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='right'>Top Image Label:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=TopLabel value="<?php echo $a1['TopLabel'];?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php
            for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
            {
                if($a1['ItemImage'.$i] != "")
                {
                     echo "<tr>";
                     echo "<td></td><td><img src='".$__uploadfolder.$a1['ItemImage'.$i]."' width='72' border='0'><br><a href='DeleteImage.php?".$__id."=".$a1[$__id]."&Type=gallery&file=".$a1['ItemImage'.$i]."&id=".$i."'>Delete Image</a></td>";
                     echo "</tr>";
                }

                echo "<TR><TD align='right'>Image $i: </TD><TD><input type=file name='ItemImage$i'></TD></TR>\n\t";
                echo "<TR><TD align='right'>Label $i: </td><TD><input type=text name='ItemLabel".$i."' value='".cleaninput($a1['ItemLabel'.$i],"ss|hd|tr")."' size='79'></TD></TR>\n\t";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='OldImage$i' value='".$a1['ItemImage'.$i]."'>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='OldLabel$i' value='".cleaninput($a1['ItemLabel'.$i],"ss|hd|tr")."'>";
            }
?>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="OldTopImage" value="<?php echo $a1['TopImage'];?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="OldTopLabel" value="<?php echo $a1['TopLabel'];?>">
        <input type="hidden" name=<?php echo $__id;?> value="<?php echo $_POST[$__id];?>">
        <input type="submit" name="s100" value="Edit Gallery">
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
<?php
    exit();
}
if(!empty($_GET[Start]))
{
    $Start = $_GET[Start];
}
else
{
    $Start = '0';
}

$ByPage = "10";

//get the products list
$r1 = mysql_query("select * from devbg_gallery order by ordering_id ASC limit $Start,$ByPage") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($r1) == '0')
{
    echo "<center>You have no items at the database!</center>";
    exit();
}
?>
<form method=post>
<table align=center width=500 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr style="background-color:#b5c3ce; color:white; font-family:verdana; font-size:11; font-weight:bold">
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>User</td>
    <td align='center'>Edit</td>
    <td align='center'>Delete</td>
</tr>
<?php
$col = "white";
$i=0;
while($a1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1))
{
    $r2 = mysql_query("select * from tbl_register where GID = '".$a1['ItemID']."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $a2 = mysql_fetch_array($r2);
    $name = $a2['firstname'] . " " . $a2['lastname'];

    $i++;
    if($col == "white" )
    {
        $col = "#f3f6f8";
    }
    else
    {
        $col = "white";
    }

    echo "<tr bgcolor=$col>
          <td>".$a1['ItemName']."</td>
          <td>".$name."</td>";
    echo "<td align=center><input type=radio name='".$__id."' value='".$a1[$__id]."'></td>
          <td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='DelItem[]' value='".$a1[$__id]."'></td>
          </tr>\n\n";

}
    echo "<tr>
            <td colspan=4 align=right><br>\n\t<input class=input type=submit name=ds value='Edit Selected'>  <input type='submit' class='input' name='ds' value='Delete Selected'></td>
          </tr>
</table>
</form>\n\n";

//build the "next" - "prev" navigatioin
$qnav = "select * from ".$__table." order by ItemName ";
$rnav = mysql_query($qnav) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($rnav);
        echo  "<br><table align=center width=600>";
        echo "<td align=center><font face=verdana size=2> | ";
        $pages = ceil($rows/$ByPage);

        for($i = 0; $i <= ($pages); $i++)
        {
            $PageStart = $ByPage*$i;
            $i2 = $i + 1;
            if($PageStart == $Start)
            {
                $links[] = " <span class=bodybold>$i2</span>\n\t ";
            }
            elseif($PageStart < $rows)
            {
                $links[] = " <a class=bodybold href=EditGallery.php?Start=$PageStart>$i2</a>\n\t "; 
            }
        }
        $links2 = implode(" | ", $links);
        echo $links2;
        echo  "| </td>";
        echo "</table><br>\n";
?>
<?php include("footer.php");?>
```

If there's any other information I could provide that would help find a solution, I can post it straight up. This problem has really messed with my head, and my client needs his gallery running! Makes me wish I could have coded this myself and got there before his previous developer. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Run phpinfo() and check the memory limit. Try to set it to 128M using a .htacces file.

Comment: The decrease in capability from 40+ to 19 images can surely be caused by moving to another server. But also what sizes do your client upload? Having plenty of large images can be very slow to upload and cause timeouts or stopped by server limits. Do you get any error? You should look into  upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and max_input_time in the PHP config. You can set these parameters in your php.ini, in .htaccess or even in the script itself - but depending on your host.

Comment: Well I'm sure it's nothing to do with image sizes or timeouts, because I've taken to try uploading very small images, and also uploading an extra one after one batch of 19 just so I know that it's only a single image uploading. This is what confuses me and makes me think, is it really a server issue?:

On a gallery that previously had over **30 images uploaded**, I deleted **image 26**, and attempted to reupload it with a different image, but it didn't work. I did the same with **image 17**, but it worked. So I have **no idea**... Can anyone see something I'm missing??

Comment: Please post the error messages you get.

Comment: Memory limit is set at **256M** :/

Comment: I don't actually receive any error messages. It just doesn't seem to pick up that I'm uploading any images **after the 19th input field**. Is there any error log I can actually check in-case there are some that it isn't reporting??

Answer (score 3):

A friend of mine figured out that when I moved host, my **max_file_uploads** setting in my php.ini was set to **20**, and that the code you see above loops each image and tries to upload it, even if there is no image, which explains why even if I only tried to upload 1 by itself, it wouldn't upload any after 19. Just a simple setting overlooked.

Changed this to **max_file_uploads = 100** in my ini, everything works fine now, client happy!